# Time complexity of euclidean distance

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

How can I calculate the time compelxity of euclidean distance, which is calculated with this formula:

[image]

Comment: `O(n`)`. If you want to go deep down, you can evaluate how square root is calculated. There are many methods

Comment: @Surya Since x86 has the fsqrt FPU instruction, square root calculation is constant and so are all IEEE floating point operations.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, let's see. How many operations do we have?

- `n` subtractions `(xi - yi)`
- `n` squares of the previous
- `n-1` further additions to add them up
- one square root at the end.

So each of these is (at most) linear in `n`, and hence so is the whole algorithm. (Assuming that determining the `xi` and `yi` are also no worse than `O(1)`.)

Comment: The other answer (now deleted) got me to thinking: this *can* actually be `O(n^2)` if your vector implementation is *horrific* and takes `O(n)` for doing a `x[i]` access